# Phppgadmin not working on localhost , WAMP(bitnami)

Tags: php, postgresql, apache, pgadmin, phppgadmin

I've installed wamp for Windows from this website: https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp/installer .
I can run the 127.0.0.1 (localhost) , but when I try to enter the 127.0.0.1/phppgadmin/ I get no found message.
Does anyone now how to solve this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you enable it?

Comment: @tom, I have a similar problem with WAPP (which I think the original poster also meant). In the installation wizard, PhpPgAdmin is grayed out and cannot be selected to enable it.